# use Xamarin in visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

My computer's hardware configuration are window 7, 4GB RAM,Intel Corei3 processor. I have  downloaded Xamarin studio from the internet properly in my computer.
i want to configure  andriod and ISO into my computer.how to configure.

Comment: Try google. It will likely have a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

For Android :
While installing Xamarin it must have setup the Android into your PC by default.

For iOS :
You can use a separate MAC machine as a build host to run and debug your app. The below link will help you to set up a build host.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-79L9yDQkss